# how to delete workspace in interactor?

Tags: interactor-backend

I went to system menu but could not find delete function for workspaces.
Help ? to get possible command options but could not find a function for deleting workspace.

I couldn't locate delete function within the workspace as well. Help ? within the workspace did not show delete function either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workspaces are similar to objects in the configure menu which use the "no" keyword to remove configuration.

To create a workspace:

```
[interactor] > workspace abc
```

To remove a workspace:

```
[interactor] > no workspace abc
```

Similarly, to create a service:

```
[interactor] workspace-abc-configure > service test
```

To remove a service:

```
[interactor] workspace-abc-configure > no service test
```